# JSLink support for document libraries in the Modern UI

Tags: jslink, modern-experience, modern-document-library

do JSLink customizations work well in the modern UI for document libraries?

I saw couple of articles which says  [NO JS/CSS Customization in modern UI](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)

Please advise on the same

Answer (score 3):

JSLink will not work, there are a few alternative options. However, you should carefully analyze your current JSLink business logic and compare available options in modern UI.
If you have heavy javascript customizations with JSLink, most likely you won't be able to successfully port everything to modern UI.

Here are the alternative options I was talking about:

- [Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) - it only supports UI styling customizations for columns via JSON, javascript isn't allowed
- [Field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) - you can use javascript to change look and feel of a column inside listview.
- [ListView Command Set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) - extends the SharePoint command surfaces to add new actions, and provides client-side code that you can use to implement behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint Online modern interface list/library view, the JSLINK will not work.

We can use the column formatting to achieve the same requirement, the following official document for your reference:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)